# Do you keep your provisioning profiles in version control?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, version-control

Do you keep the `.mobileprovision` files that Apple provides through the iOS provision portal in your version control system?

On the one hand, if they're included, then the VCS has all that's needed to build a new version of the software. On the other hand, they're generated artifacts to some extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't. It can be regenerated at any time in the portal and they expire anyway. So they're kind of useless after a while.